# Making palindromes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, palindrome

I am trying to write a function that takes in a string and makes a palindrome out of it.

For example, `ace` becomes `aceeca`.

Answer (score 7):

Pretty easy, just concatenate the reversed string onto itself.

```
palindrome s = s ++ reverse s
```

++ is the list concatenation function.

Let me point you toward [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/).  It's a good book for learning the language if you're just getting started.

Comment: Funny how the term "pointless" has caught on.  I originally saw that as a joke on what I think is the original term "point free".

Comment: @TomMD: I like the term pointless more, as it always reminds me that excessive usage of pointless style leads to truely pointless code like `flip ((.) . take) . drop`.

Answer (score 0):

```
palindrome [] = []
palindrome (x:xs) = append (x:(palindrome xs)) x
  where append (x:xs) y = x:(append xs y)
        append [] y = [y]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!